# How to combine Node.js and Browser console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an Node.js Application that writes a String to a file on the disc.
How can I access this file from the Browser Console?
Is it possible to access this file?

---

Sorry I had to edit the question.
My initial question was how to open an url.

```
var url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/sendphone=123456789&text=a%20test%20message';
var start = (process.platform == 'darwin'? 'open': process.platform == 'win32'? 'start': 'xdg-open');
require('child_process').exec(start + ' ' + url);
```

Comment: Do you want to open url in same/next browser tab ?

Comment: The browser is not open yet. I need the program to open a browser and open the url. I know how to do this from the developer consoler, but this time I need to do this from an external JS file.

Comment: Assume you have some js file then how are you going to execute this file ? This is what i am asking. Can you explain your problem in more depth.

Comment: There might be because `opn` already deprecated and they're not support for your OS or something. Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

Comment: `It is an external js file.` it is not clear what you mean with the term `external`. It is better to say where/how the js file is used in which e.g. is the javascript code executed in a browser, nodejs, electron, ...

Comment: ah ok, I meant by this executed in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way we can use XMLHttpRequest to open particular url and extract some information from it.

```
var txt = '';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=a%20test%20message',true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Looks good, I did install it with `npm install xmlhttprequest` but still get the Error `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: ok I also installed  the xhr2 module, so the Error disappeared, but the url is not opened ;/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 'opn-url' module before using it:

```
npm install opn-url
```

Then the following modified code should work:

```
var opn = require('opn-url');
//opens the url in the default browser
opn.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=a%20test%20message');
```

Here a complete bash script which creates a project and runs it. You need a Linux/Mac OS X machine to run. It should also work under Windows in a Linux emulation environment (e.g. mingw).

To use it copy the whole script to the clipboard, open a console (terminal), paste it and press the enter key:

```
mkdir testurl && cd testurl && npm init --yes && npm install opn-url && cat <<EOF >testurl.js
var opn = require('opn-url');
opn.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com/'); //opens the url in the default browser
EOF
node testurl.js
```

Comment: I am getting this Error:```events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)```

Comment: Did you create a new Node.js project using 'npm init' and then install the module 'opn-url' in that project directory with the command 'npm install opn-url'?
Have you copied the 3 sourcecode lines I posted into a new 'testurl.js' file and then started this script using 'node testurl.js'? If not, can you please try that as a first step? Do I assume right, that you use node.js? Which version do you use?

Your error message looks like you have more code which you didn't show to us.

Comment: No I created a new project, with only this 3 lines. I have the latest version, as I installed everything 3 days ago, since I started learning javaschript.

Comment: Can you please try what I wrote under "Here a complete bash script..."?